# Файловая система

Tags: файловая-система, модули, ос, ядро, внешние-устройства

Мы знаем, что ОС имеет 2 группы модулей.

1. модули, выполняющее основные функции ОС – модули ядра;
2. модули, выполняющие вспомогательные функции ОС.

Модули ядра – выполняют 3 базовые функции ОС, как:

- управление процессами
- управление памятью
- управление устройствами ввода-вывода

Вспомогательные  модули подразделяются на 4 группы:

- утилиты
- библиотеки процедур и функций различного назначения
- программы предоставления пользователю дополнительных услуг
- системные обрабатывающие программы

Теперь я не могу понять где здесь файловая система? Т.е. куда она относится?

Comment: в "управление устройствами ввода-вывода".